# How to change only primary Wordpress menu dynamically on login?

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, authentication, menu

I am using the code below to show a menu called "logged-in" when the user is logged in, and a menu called "logged-out" when they are logged out. But on my pages, I have a main menu and a secondary menu. This code changes both menus to be identical. I would like my secondary menu to not change based on logged-in status and only have my primary menu change. Thanks.

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {

if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
    $args['menu'] = 'logged-in';
} else { 
    $args['menu'] = 'logged-out';
} 
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

I feel like it is in this part of the code but I am not sure what to put in the $args[' '] part.

```
$args['menu'] = 'logged-in';
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to qualify the location of the menu you want to change, otherwise it will run anywhere `wp_nav_menu_args` is run. To do this, just wrap the code in an `if` statement checking for the `theme_location` that's set.

Based on your theme, the location name may change, so confirm that; It will typically be something like `primary`.

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {

if( $args['theme_location'] == 'primary' ){
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
        $args['menu'] = 'logged-in';
    } else { 
        $args['menu'] = 'logged-out';
    }
}
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

Below I've made your function a bit more succinct, but it accomplishes the same thing:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'logged_in_out_menu' );
function logged_in_out_menu( $args ){
    if( $args['theme_location'] == 'primary' ){
        // Only run this modification on the `primary` nave menu
        $args['menu'] = is_user_logged_in() ? 'logged-in' : 'logged-out';
    }

    return $args;
}
```